# How do I dynamically add different elements for when the user clicks a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, local-storage

[Here](http://output.jsbin.com/taguda#) is the link to the site.

The layout of the page consists of a "fixed" sidebar (left), in which buttons are created when a user clicks the "Add" button, accompanied by their chosen title and amount of points the button is worth. Then, when the button is clicked, the button disappears and the points are added on to the "Points" value, which is in the middle "div" of the page.

On the far right there is an empty div, I tried to make the same kind of thing, except I could never get it to work. What I wanted was to create another similar dynamically created button or "span" of some sort, where when the user clicks it, the points allocated to said button/span are the deducted from the total number of points. I was thinking of it as a redeeming system if that makes sense. Using coins, which I would just assign to be half the number of points.

Also, I was able to simply store the number of points and the level in localStorage, but I wasn't sure how to store the created buttons, so they disappear after every refresh, and I can't figure out how to do it, since they're not specifically coded in?

Also, if possible, how would I go about a notification div that creates an alert for each button that is clicked. The alert would say something along the lines of "You have completed *task name*", and it would store it in localStorage, so the user can see the buttons that were clicked in notification form.

One more thing, upon creating the button, there is a title and a number of points the user has to assign, under the second input text box, there are 5 different coloured "spans", each representing a different "field" you might say, in this case it's different subject, how would I make it so that when the user clicks one of the "Spans", the button created will be the same colour as the span they clicked?

I know I'm asking for a lot, but I have tried to do all of which I've asked for and have had massive troubles. If anyone thinks they can help me out It would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Here is the code, html and javascript. The CSS is bootstrap.

HTML

```
  <div >


      <div id='header'>

        <h2 style='font-size:71px'>Reward System</h2>

        <div>
            <ol class="breadcrumb" style="width:58%">
                <li class="active">
                   <center> <a href="#">Home</a> 
                </li>

                <li>
                   <a href="#">About</a> 
                </li>

                <li>
                  <a href="#">Refresh</a> </center>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div></div><center>
 <div id='main'>
<div id='rightSide' class='well'>




</div>



        <div class='well' id="addc" style='width:520px'>
            <div id="addc">
                <input class='form-control' maxlength="15" id="btnName" placeholder="New Task"
                style='width:480px' type="text"><br>
                <input maxlength="3" class='form-control' id="btnPoints" placeholder="Points"
                style='width:480px' type="text"><br>



              <span class="label label-danger">Mathematics EX1</span>
        <span class="label label-primary">Mathematics EX2</span>
              <span class="label label-success">Physics</span> 
              <span class="label label-info">Chemistry</span> 
              <span class=
        "label label-warning">English Advanced</span><br>
        <br>
                <button id="addBtn" >Add</button>  

            </div>
        </div>



        <div class='panel panel-default' style='width:520px;height:100px'>
            <h3><Strike>z</strike> Points</span></h3>


            <div class='badge' id="result">
                0
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr style="width:520px;">

        <div class='panel panel-default' style="width:520px;">
            <h3>Level</h3>

            <p class='badge' style='width:50px' id='lvl'>0</p>

            <div class="progress" style='width:300px'>
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" id='perce'
                style="width;"></div>
            </div>
        </div><br>
    </div>


<div id='leftSide' class='well'>
  <center>  <h3> Tasks </h3> </center>

   <div class='well' id="container" style='width:260px;height:85%'>
        </div>

  <div id='reset'>
        <button class='btn btn-warning' onclick='clearme()'>Reset</button>
    </center>
    </div>

</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var resDiv = document.getElementById('result');
resDiv.innerText = localStorage.getItem('myResult');

var levelDiv = document.getElementById('lvl');
levelDiv.textContent = localStorage.getItem('myLevel');


var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        addToResult(this.getAttribute('data-points'));
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this.nextElementSibling);
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    });
}


var addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn');
addBtn.className = "btn btn-default";
addBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    var objDiv = document.getElementById("container");
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;


    var btnName = document.getElementById('btnName').value;
    var btnPoints = parseInt(document.getElementById('btnPoints').value);
    if (!btnName)
        btnName = "Button ?";
    if (!btnPoints)
        btnPoints = 50;
    var newBtn = document.createElement('button');
    var newPnt = document.createElement('span');

    newBtn.className = 'btn btn-info';


    newBtn.innerText = btnName;
    newBtn.setAttribute('data-points', btnPoints);
    newBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        addToResult(this.getAttribute('data-points'));
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this.nextElementSibling);
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    });
    newPnt.className = 'label label-default';
    newPnt.innerText = "+" + btnPoints;
    container.appendChild(newBtn);
    container.appendChild(newPnt);
});


function addToResult(pts) {
    // NaN is falsy, so you can just use || to make a fall-back to 0
    var result = parseInt(resDiv.innerText, 10) || 0,
        lvl = 0,
        a = 100;
    result = result + parseInt(pts, 10) || 0;



  var pen = (result/500)*100;

    while (result > (5 * a)) {
        lvl += 1;
        a += 100;
        pen -= 100; 

    }





    document.getElementById('perce').style.width = pen +"%";



    resDiv.innerText = result;
    levelDiv.innerText = lvl;
    localStorage.setItem("myResult", result);
    localStorage.setItem("myLevel", levelDiv.textContent);


}





function clearme() {
  localStorage.clear();
}
```

Comment: How were you able to put bounty on a question with such a low reputation? And you really need to learn how to ask. The way you are asking is just like saying "I want to make a point system. How?" except that the specification is clear. You will be able to hire a freelancer with the content above, but to get help from a forum, your question are not specific enough. At least, the "Also" and "One more thing" can be separated into another 3 questions.

Comment: It wasn't low at all until the bounty, I know what you mean, I worded it terribly, it's unfortunate. Shall I assume no help from a forum user is gonna come from anyone who sees a -7 reputation..

Answer (score 1):

To keep your buttons in `localStorage` you will need to create your own object that holds the button's name and points, then use `JSON.stringify` to turn an array of these objects into a string. That string can then be used with `localStorage.setItem`

```
function MyButtonObject(name,points){
    this.name=name;
    this.points=points;
}

var list=[new MyButtonObject('example',100)];

localStorage.setItem( 'btnList' , JSON.stringify(list) );
```

Next I would procede by seperating the code that makes a new buttons into its own function so it can be called when the page loads and you want to rebuild your button elements.

```
var listJSON=localStorage.setItem( 'btnList' );
var list= listJSON?JSON.parse(listJSON ):[];

list.forEach(function(btn){
    makeButtonElements(btn);
});

function makeButtonElements(btn){
    var btnName=btn.name, btnPoints=btn.points;

    var newBtn = document.createElement('button');
    var newPnt = document.createElement('span');

....etc....
```

Your existing function that creates buttons would call this one as well as creating a new `MyButtonObject` adding it to the array of said objects and storing that array with `localStorage.setItem`. The function that removes buttons will need updating to remove the correct object from the array and calling `localStorage.setItem` as well as adding your planned notification messages (and storing them).

You should probably take some time to plan what other features you might want (such as deleting buttons without scoring their points, displaying notifications etc) and think about how you can break those processes down into functions that can be reused at different points in your program (eg new button/notification created, existing button/notification loaded from storage)

Here is a handy function that copies a style property from one element to another that should help you set the buttons colours the way you want.

```
function copyStyle(prop,fromEl,toEl){
    toEl.style[prop]=window.getComputedStyle(fromEl)[prop];
}
```

*Note: I haven't check or tested any of this code so make sure you read through it and understand what it is meant to do before you start copying and pasting into your own program.*